# java cv -v stitch - exception

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, image-stitching

I try to use javacv to stitch images. I get an exception and I can't solve it.

This is the code:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_stitching.*;

public class App {

static boolean try_use_gpu = false;
static MatVector imgs = new MatVector();
static String result_name = "result.jpg";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Mat pano = new Mat();
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher.createDefault(try_use_gpu);

    stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);
    imwrite(result_name, pano);
}

static void parseCmdArgs(String[] args) {

    Mat img = imread("image1.jpg");
    Mat img2 = imread("image2.jpg");

    imgs.resize(imgs.size() + 1);
    imgs.put(imgs.size() - 1, img);

    imgs.resize(imgs.size() + 1);
    imgs.put(imgs.size() - 1, img2);
}
}
```

This is the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_stitching$Stitcher.stitch(Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core$MatVector;Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core$Mat;)I
>     at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_stitching$Stitcher.stitch(Native
>   Method)

I get the exception when I invoke the function of stitch ( stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano); ).

I don't know how I can handle this. What is my mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you follow the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv)?

Comment: Actually my code is the same. I found that example and I followed it.

Comment: Are you using Maven? If not, can you explain how your are building?

Comment: I use Maven and it contains that dependency which is in the example

Comment: Did you call `mvn` with the `-Dplatform.dependencies` command line option? You might also be hitting this bug: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/28 ?